# MongoDB very slow deleteMany and remove

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In my MongoDB with 2 replicas I have a collection with over 100 million documents, the size of the collection is over 400 GB and the indexes size is 150 GB. I have to reduce the size of the collection by removing the oldest records using `modifiedOn` field for which I have a TTL index. The TTL index will remove entries older than a month but I have to act now. I've tried to remove the oldest records using:

```
db.myCollection.deleteMany({modifiedOn : {"$lt" : new Date(2021, 12, 20}})
```

and

```
db.myCollection.remove({modifiedOn : {"$lt" : new Date(2021, 12, 20}})
```

I was trying to increment the day and then execute the query to reduce the load but it takes at least 10 hours to complete these queries. I know that dropping the collection is the fastest option but I want to preserve the latest data.

Why exactly does it take so long to execute these queries even with an index for `modifiedOn`, is the index too big and updating it takes so long? What are better options to delete the oldest records?

Comment: Deleting so many records simply takes some time. Maybe you could create one collection per months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to temporarily modify TTL value ([documentation here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/collMod/#change-expiration-value-for-indexes)):

```
db.runCommand({
collMod: 'collection',
index: {keyPattern: {field_name: 1}, expireAfterSeconds: 120}
});
```

Comment: In my case even TTL couldn't keep up deleting old entries and was behind 2 days. After researching all other options I believe that decreasing TTL should be the preferred approach because there is no point having 2 competing processes removing data (TTL competing with a remove query) and collMod operation is executed almost instantly.